# Axon State-Stored Aggregate Test IllegalStateException

Tags: spring-boot, axon

PROBLEM: Customer technical limitations force me to use Axon with state-stored Aggregates in PostgreSQL. I try a simple JPA-Entity Axon-Test and get IllegalStateException.

RESEARCH: A simplified project on the case is available at https://gitlab.com/ZonZonZon/simple-axon.git

In my test on

```
fixture.givenState(MyAggregate::new)
    .when(command)
    .expectState(state -> {
      System.out.println();
    });
```

I get

> The state of this aggregate cannot be retrieved because it has been modified in a Unit of Work that was rolled back
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The state of this aggregate cannot be retrieved because it has been modified in a Unit of Work that was rolled back
> at org.axonframework.common.Assert.state(Assert.java:44)

QUESTION: How to test an aggregate state using Axon and escape the error?

Answer (score 1):

there are some missing parts in your project to let the test run properly. I will try to tackle them as concisely as possible:

- your Command should contain the piece of information that connects it to the Aggregate. `@TargetAggregateIdentifier` is the annotation provided by the framework that connects a certain field to its `@AggregateIdentifier` counterpart into your Aggregate. You can read more here https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/command-handling/aggregate#handling-commands-in-an-aggregate.
  Said so, a UUID field needs to be added to your `Create` command.
- This information will be then passed into the `Created` event : events are stored and can be processed both by a replay or an Aggregate re-hydration (upon client’s restart). (These) are the source of truth for our information.
- `@EventSourcingHandler` annotated method will be responsible for applying the event and updating the `@Aggregate` values

  ```
  public void on(Created event) {
       uuid = event.getUuid();
       login = event.getLogin();
       password = event.getPassword();
       token = event.getToken();
  }
  ```
- the test will then look like

  ```
  public void a_VideochatAccount_Created_ToHaveData() {

     Create command = Create.builder()
                            .uuid(UUID.randomUUID())
                            .login("123")
                            .password("333")
                            .token("d00a1f49-9e37-4976-83ae-114726938c73")
                            .build();

     Created expectedEvent = Created.builder()
                                   .uuid(command.getUuid())
                                   .login(command.getLogin())
                                   .password(command.getPassword())
                                   .token(command.getToken())
                                   .build();

     fixture.givenNoPriorActivity()
            .when(command)
            .expectEvents(expectedEvent);
  }
  ```

This test will validate your **Command Part** of your CQRS.

I will then suggest to separate the **Query Part** from your `@Aggregate`: you will then need to handle events with `@EventHandler` annotation placed on a method into a Projection `@Component` class, and implement the piece of logic that will take care of storing the information in the form that you need into PostgreSQL `@Entity`, using the `@Repository` JPA way, which I am sure you are familiar with.
You can find useful information on the ref guide https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/event-handling following the video example on The Query Model based on code that you can be found in this repo https://github.com/AxonIQ/food-ordering-demo/tree/master

Hope that all is clear,

Corrado.

Comment: You.ve pointed me the right direction. I should have passed the `id` to command and shouldn't have created it in command handler. But why can't I validate the state: `fixture.givenState`? Updated the project.

Comment: In my opinion a test should be narrow as possible: in our case we would like to test that upon a certain command, an event is applied and handled by the Aggregate. This will validate our aggregate state too.
If you want to test that the expected value is sent to your repository, I will then create a second test that will focus on the Query part, or eventually an end-to-end (integration) test. In this case you should take into account that a delay can be present from the moment that you trigger your command until it will be written in your database .

Comment: Sorry, in your case that you decided to go with a state stored aggregate, test fixture using givenState is perfectly fine.

Here a piece of ref guide that can help you
https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/command-handling/testing#validating-aggregate-state

Comment: That's what the quiestion is about. This state throws an exception. You can run a test in Gitlab project enclosed to see.